# Can't find a way to add Game Over in my flash game as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

So i followed this tutorial [Asgamer Flash Game](http://asgamer.com/2009/flash-game-design-basics-adding-library-objects-to-stage-with-as3).
I finished the tutorial and i cant find a way how to make my game when the ship goes 0 health must take you to another screen saying Game Over.I tried this code from [How to game over AS3](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1217498) but i get confused how to write the code ( i used as3 classes).

```
add to vars

var sKills:Number;
var sPoints:Number;

add to health deduction function

if (health <= 0 && lives <=0) {
sKills = kills;
sPoints = points;
die();
}

add function anywhere

function die();
kills = 0;
points = 0;
health = 100;
lives = 10;
//basically reset all game values besides sKills and sPoints
gotoAndStop("gameover");
}
```

i have severall as3 classes
Engine
Ship
EnemyUFO 
i dont know where to insert this code in which class

Comment: i edit the question with the code

Comment: do you have a frame with a "gameover" label?

Comment: yes after the frame with the game

Comment: and "die" function is running? did you tried to put there a trace?

Comment: i typed the code into my engine class and i get the following errors 
`Line 92 1120: Access of undefined property kills.
Line 92 1120: Access of undefined property score.
Line 92 1120: Access of undefined property hits.`

Comment: where you defined these variables?

Comment: `private var numStar:int = 80;
  private var numCloud:int = 5;
  public static var enemyList:Array = new Array();
  private var ourShip:Ship;
  public var s_hits:Number;
  public var s_kills:Number;
  public var s_score:Number;
  private var scoreHUD:ScoreHUD;
`

Comment: any news ?> i m very stuck

Comment: no , pack your project into zip and send me

Comment: how do i send it to u?

Comment: place it somewhere on web and send me url

Comment: Man , i can't open your files .  i'm using flash cs4 , and it seems your version is above , sorry

Comment: anyone else that can help me